# replacing rows in pandas with certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns say : 'form_field' and 'field_value', like this:

```
   form_field   field_value
0            1             4
1            2             4
2            3             1
3            4             1
4            5             4
5            6             1
6            7             1
7            8             3
8            9             1
```

now I want for certain form_fileds that the value corresponding to it in the field_value should be replaced.
for eg say for form_field 1,4,9 I want the field_values to be changed in this manner that if it is a 1 then change it to 4, if it is a 2 then change it to 3, if 3 change it to 2 and if 4 change it to 1.
so I tried putting all the form_filed values that need to be changed in a list named "e" and ran the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np


all_files = os.listdir("Trap_data/") 
os.chdir(r"Trap_data/") 
e=[1,2,5,8,10,11,15,16,19,20,21,23,26,27,30,33,34,36,39]

for file in all_files:  

    f_name = file
    df_1 = pd.read_csv(f_name,nrows=40)
    
    for i in e:
      
        df_1['form_field'][i] = pd.to_numeric((df_1[' field_value'][i]), errors='coerce').replace([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1])
print(df_1)
```

however that throws an error :

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Use `.map({old:new, old1:new1})` so just mapping old->new e.g {1:4, 2:3,3:2,4:1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code to:

```
#e=[1,2,5,8,10,11,15,16,19,20,21,23,26,27,30,33,34,36,39]
e= [1, 4, 9]

val_map = {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}

df.loc[df['form_field'].isin(e), 'field_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['field_value'], errors='coerce').replace(val_map)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   form_field   field_value
0            1             4
1            2             4
2            3             1
3            4             1
4            5             4
5            6             1
6            7             1
7            8             3
8            9             1
```

Comment: gives new columns with title  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5 filled with NaN values

Comment: @Kshtj  Is your data applying the code the same as the sample data ?

Comment: @Kshtj  Note that you don't need to put the codes in the inner loop of `for i ...`

Comment: am not sure I understand the statement, do u mean what format data is in? if yes then the data is an excel sheet with two columns as mentioned and values filled in them , for form_field the values are from 1 to 40 and for form_values it is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.Basically its a survey questionarrie if that helps.

Comment: am not using the for loop of 'i' now, am just using the code u mentioned

Comment: @Kshtj  Are you still putting the codes in the `for file ...` loop ?

Comment: @Kshtj  You read the data into `df_1` and my codes use `df` instead.  You replaced the name before execution ?

Comment: yes because I want to do this for all the excel sheets in the named folder.

Comment: @Kshtj  You have more than one file  to read ?  If yes, but your `print(df_1)` only appear after the loop ?  In that case, you are printing only the result of last file.  Are you sure the last file has the same layout as your sample data ?

Comment: @Kshtj  You better test with one file without the loop to make sure the new codes work first.  Then extend further to multiple files.  For the single test file, make sure the layout is the same as your sample data first (e.g. by printing it first before running the new codes)

Comment: yes , if i push the df_1 inside the loop it prints for all files . yep the data is same for all where serial number 1 is the header titled form_field and form_value and from serial number2 values for each question starts and it goes till serial number 41 (as there are total 40 questions and first line is used by headings.)

Comment: i tried for 1 file it works fine , but for multiple files it messes up for some files, idk why , even tho they format is same.I checked mannually too.

Comment: @Kshtj  Is that you have 40 files for 40 questions but only the first one has the header titles ?  If yes, then except the first file, all the other 39 files will not got the column labels from the header titles.   You have to copy the header titles to all csv files then.

Comment: just rechecked all files have same format with line 1 as header and from line 2 to line 41 questions and their responses.So all of them have same thing. I dont know why the NaN thing is coming for some files only.I guess if it is not solvable then i will have to remove their data , which can fix the problem here but still theoritically i would be very curious what went wrong in these files despite having same format.

Comment: @Kshtj  Does all of them have the proper field separators as comma ?  I think you can inspect the data of those files that are invalid in this direction.

Comment: @Kshtj  Or would some of your data contents contain comma ?  If yes, then it will have conflict with the CSV field separator and make the CSV can't interpret whether it is a new field or part of a text field that contains comma.

Comment: there is no separation the data looks like this :                                                     form_field  field_value
1                      2
2                      2
3                      3
4                      3
5                      2
6 3
7 1
8 3

Comment: form_field  field_value
1 2
2 2
3 3
4 3
5 2
6 3
7 1
8 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233698/discussion-between-kshtj-and-seabean).

Answer (score 0):

Using this data:

```
   form_field   field_value
0            1             4
1            2             4
2            3             1
3            4             1
4            5             4
5            6             1
6            7             1
7            8             3
8            9             1
```

then:

```py
# copy the above, read into dataframe
# df = pd.read_clipboard(sep="\s+")

maps = {
    1: 4,
    2: 3,
    3: 2,
    4: 1,
}

df.loc[df["form_field"].isin(maps.keys()), "field_value"] = df.loc[
    df["form_field"].isin(maps.keys()), "form_field"
].replace(maps)
```

Gives:

```
   form_field  field_value
0           1            4
1           2            3
2           3            2
3           4            1
4           5            4
5           6            1
6           7            1
7           8            3
8           9            1
```

Comment: doest give the output in desired format. adds many unnecessary columns,here have a look:

Comment: @Kshtj please explain properly, with a data example, there are the same columns in the output as the input so what you're saying doesn't make sense to me